# SQL unique values for a group of values

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

I have 2 columns 'id' and 'date' in a table, I want to avoid to insert repeated dates for the same id, I mean

```
id  |  date 
------------------
1  | 01/01/2015 
2  | 01/01/2015
3  | 02/01/2015
1  | 01/01/2015 <--- this value is already insert for id 1, and should not be allowed for id 1
```

Comment: before inserting check whether it is already there? or use `unique` constraint for the both id and date

Comment: isn't `id` the primary key ?

Comment: Yes the answer was to add unique constraint for both id and date!!! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A safe way to handle your situation would be to add a unique constraint on the combination of the `id` and `date` columns:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE `ui`(`id`, `date`);
```

After adding this constraint, an attempt to insert a duplicate record will generate an error.  As a note, if you use this option it will also remove duplicates which already exist in your table.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the question is you do not want two rows to have the same value.  You can use the unique keyword, but that would restrict the column to only have one of each value.  So it will not allow id 1 and 2 to both have the same date.

If you really don't want to duplicate rows, then you need to check to see if the row is already in the table.  If it is not there then add the row.

The other option is to add the duplicate rows and then use a "select distinct" when searching the database.